# Adding Calculator to Cognito Form to create delivery charge line item

Tags: cognito-forms, calculator

I created an order form for my bakery. It has a radio button to select order pickup or delivery, and a repeating section with fields to select flavors and quantity. If the customer chooses order delivery, I want to have a graduated local delivery fee added to the order. For example: Order total up to $60 - add $5 delivery fee, Order Total $61 to $120 - add $10 delivery fee, $121 to $180 - add $15 delivery fee. How do I create a calculator in my form to add this conditional line item to the payment section?

Answer (score 1):

To do this:

1. Add a Price field to your form called Delivery Fee.
2. Under the Show This Field option, set the field to only appear when a customer selects Delivery from your Choice field:

[image]

3. Add an Order Total field (if you don't have one already). You can calculate an order total from repeating sections by summing the Item Total from each section:
   `=MyOrder.Sum(ItemTotal)`
4. In the Amount section of your Price field, reference your Order Total with a series of if/then statements:

`=(if OrderTotal <=60 then 5 else 0) + (if OrderTotal >= 61 and OrderTotal <= 120 then 10 else 0) + (if OrderTotal >=121 and OrderTotal<=180 then 15 else 0)`

5. Now, when a customer selects Delivery from the Choice field, it will automatically apply a delivery fee of $5.00, which increases incrementally with the Order Total.